# Swift Camera crash, Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

Tags: swift4

I am getting a crash from the camera in my app. I present the imagePicker controller and when I take a picture it crashes, even before the imagepicker controller ask you if you want to use the picture or retake it. Therefore my code does not even get called. The problem is not present when I record video or when I choose a photo from the library. The memory is around 110 MB

This is the info I am getting usually form the debugger before it crashes

```[GatekeeperXPC] Connection to assetsd was interrupted or assetsd died
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue'''

Comment: You ever figure this out? I just developed the same problem when taking a picture with the Picker Camera in my app. no problem with it during over a month of development, now it suddenly crashes with the memory issue message...

Comment: No, I have not being able to solve it. The app still crashes.